# What is the java keyevent field for dot '.'?

Tags: java, keyevent

I know how to call 1 using keyevent which should be like aaa.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);

Now I need to type (.) dot? But I could not find (KeyEvent.VK_DOT) or some similar command. Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

The "dot" is called a *period*; hence it's [`VK_PERIOD`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_PERIOD).

Answer (score 10):

Very old question, very basic question, but the correct answer is missing.

For regular dot use:

```
KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD
```

For numpad dot use:

```
KeyEvent.VK_DECIMAL
```

Answer (score 3):

[VK_PERIOD](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_PERIOD) should do what you need.

Answer (score 3):

`VK_PERIOD` WILL **NOT** get it done, by the way. Sometimes the "painfully obvious" answer doesn't quite work.

`VK_PERIOD` DOES **NOT** pick up the numpad's dot. It gets the main period, but you're left wonder why it no worky for numpad.

In case you need to respect numpad's dot (which is a strong possibility for all conceivable uses of a dot) you'll have to go with

```
keyEvent.getKeyChar() == '.'
```

Or (if you must have your KeyCodes)

```
keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD || keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DECIMAL
```

will also work.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Java 8 with Apache Netbeans. `VK_PERIOD` works fine with both decimals and dot.