# What is the java keyevent field for question mark?

Tags: java, keyevent

Is there any event for pressing ?, such as `keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_?)` in Java?

Comment: You've asked [two questions in a row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384996/what-is-the-java-keyevent-field-for-dot) about KeyEvent fields. Please (a) read the [KeyEvent documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html) and (b) put some effort into your questions. It would not be difficult to write a program which printed out the keys which were pressed, and then you could type a dot or a question mark and see for yourself what comes out.

Comment: ehhh ... "too localized" - to which narrow area, time, community is a question mark's importance limited? Fully agreed that the qustion is lacking, but such is the reason for closing ...

Answer (score 5):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html:

> Not all characters have a keycode associated with them. For example, there is no keycode for the question mark because there is no keyboard for which it appears on the primary layer.

Comment: There is indeed no keycode associated with "?" but a way to check if "?" is pressed (SHIFT + "/" for my keyboard) is to call `getKeyChar()` on a `KeyEvent` and check if that matches `'?'`.